# ApexCharts custom markers color

Tags: javascript, vue.js, apexcharts

I am using apexCharts in my vue project.
[charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5uw6.png)

I want the markers color change to yellow when the line exceeds the yellow line(warnning). And the markers color change to red when the line exceeds the red line(bad). otherwise the color of markers will turn green.

```
colors: [
      function({ value, seriesIndex, w }) {
        if (value <= this.STATUS_GOOD) {
          return MEASUREMENT_COLORS[0];
        } else if (value > this.STATUS_BAD) {
          return MEASUREMENT_COLORS[1];
        } else {
          return MEASUREMENT_COLORS[2];
        }
      }
    ],
```

I thought that could write a function in color to control the color. But I failed.
Is there any way to custom markers color?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: **Note: Note that the number of items in colors array should be equal to number of series if you intend to provide a function for it.** - from the documentation. Looks like youre only passing one value to colour. Also are there any errors?

Comment: I tried your solution, but it didn't work. I have three series. So I added two undefined after function.

Comment: are there any console errors? What do you see if you log the chart object and look at the `colors` property?

Comment: there are no error in console.

Comment: You might have to use the discrete option with markers - https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/markers/

Comment: [error](https://imgur.com/Ox979kp) There seems to be an error.

Comment: It can't be solved with discrete

Comment: https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/issues/1247

Answer (score 0):

In the chart options.

markers: {
colors: 'red',
},